# How to layout a graph in a GEF editor with prefuse

Tags: graph, data-visualization, eclipse-gef, draw2d, prefuse

Is it possible to "plug in" a prefuse layout (such as [NodeLinkTreeLayout](http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/action/layout/graph/NodeLinkTreeLayout.html)) to layout a graph in a GEF editor? Or would I have to port the algorithm to Draw2D?

Comment: So you mean that you'd be able to interact with the prefuse visualization in the GEF like a normal graph? I'd be surprised if there is built-in support for this.